# How to Call a Batch File in Powershell which is Including Whitespaces in the Directory Path

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

When I am trying to call a batch file from Powershell script as follows:

`cmd.exe /C "C:\FolderNameWithNoSpaces\Folder Name With Spaces\myScript.cmd"`

then I am encountering following error message:

`'C:\FolderNameWithNoSpaces\Folder' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The spaces in the path are creating problem.

How I can call a batch file from powershell which is located in the directory which has whitespaces in its name?

Comment: Enclose the double-quoted string in single-quotes: `cmd /c '"C:\pa th\to.file"'`

Comment: I have tried putting double-quoted string into single-quotes but nothing changed and same error message.

Comment: ``C:\FolderNameWithNoSpaces\Folder` Name` With` Spaces\myScript.cmd`` or `&'C:\FolderNameWithNoSpaces\Folder Name With Spaces\myScript.cmd'`. P.S. your command should also work. Are you execute it, as in your question, or you add arguments to it?

Comment: I can also confirm that `cmd.exe /c 'c:\some\path\with spaces\test.bat'` works on my system with single or double quotes - Powershell 4 and when using the version flag for 2 & 3. You can use Invoke-Expression or Start-Process as well but the problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: My wild guess, is that you invoking batch file **with arguments** thru `cmd.exe`. In that case you need following: ``cmd.exe /S /C `" "C:\FolderNameWithNoSpaces\Folder Name With Spaces\myScript.cmd" "arguments with spaces" `"``.

Comment: I'd simply try `cmd.exe /C ""C:\FolderNameWithNoSpaces\Folder Name With Spaces\myScript.cmd""`; `cmd` removed the outer pair of `""`, so the inner one remains so that the entire path is interpreted as one part...

Comment: As @PetSerAl pointed out, running `cmd /c "C:\path with spaces\script.cmd"` should work. Please provide evidence. Show your actual code and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$RunCMD = @'
cmd.exe /C "C:\FolderNameWithNoSpaces\Folder Name With Spaces\myScript.cmd"
'@
Invoke-Expression -Command:$RunCMD
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved me HOURS.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
C:\FolderNameWithNoSpaces\"Folder Name With Spaces"\myScript.cmd
```

Enclosing only part of the path in quotation marks.

As also described here: https://www.howtogeek.com/694949/how-to-escape-spaces-in-file-paths-on-the-windows-command-line/